# how do I dynamically change light mode to dark mode in react native in iOS?

Tags: ios, react-native

So I have a react native in iOS, and I have implemented dark and light mode in that. I need that theme to change based on the light or dark mode in my iPhone. It should change dynamically. Any idea how I should go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Use Context API or Redux Library for them in react native app.
create a global object having colors, background colors for theme, then use throghtout the app.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Appearance } from 'react-native';

const colorScheme = Appearance.getColorScheme();
if (colorScheme === 'dark') {
  // Use dark color scheme
} else {
  // Use light color scheme
}
```

**Appearance** provide information about the user's appearance preferences, such as their preferred color scheme (light or dark). You can use it to change app color scheme.

Comment: do i have to use this throughout all the screens, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It's depend on you. Check this link. You will get the idea. [link](https://blog.logrocket.com/comprehensive-guide-dark-mode-react-native)